# Current timeStamp is not getting automatically saved into the table with jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am using the below sql query to create a table in postgres DB.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data
(
    id serial, 
    created_at timestamp(0) without time zone DEFAULT (now())::timestamp(0) without time zone,
    created_by integer NOT NULL
);
```

**Entity Class:-**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Data implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7462797749946000617L;

    public Data() {
    }

    public Data(Integer createdBy) {
        super();
        this.setCreatedBy(createdBy);
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Timestamp createdAt;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private Integer createdBy;
}
```

When i am inserting the data like Date data=new Data("12312442");

```
LogsRepository.save(data);
```

The 'created_at' value is getting saved as null value in DB. Can anyone tell me what wrong am i doing?

Comment: Most probably your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") is explicitly sending a `NULL` value

Comment: Yes that is the case .. So how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fields which values are populated on DB layer you can use Hibernate annotation [@Generated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-Generated) that tells the Hibernate to **read** such values **after** persisting the entity. In your case:

```
@Column(name = "created_at")
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
private Timestamp createdAt;
```

Note then you invoke `logsRepository.save(data)` the Hibernate creates two query to DB: first - insert new data:

```
insert into data values(...)
```

second - read the generated value:

```
select created_at from data where id = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `@Column(insertable = false)`, to force JPA to ignore the column when generating `INSERT` statements, so that the default db value would apply.

However, assuming you are using spring data, why not simply `@EnableJpaAuditing` and then annotate the property with `@CreatedDate`?

Note that you could then handle `createdBy` in a similar way, by annotating it with `@CreatedBy` and providing an `AuditorAware`.

`AuditorAware` integrates nicely with Spring Security. Here's an example implementation:

```
@Component
public class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        return Optional
                    .ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())
                .filter(auth -> !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken))
                .map(Authentication::getPrincipal)
                .map(UserDetails.class::cast)
                .map(UserDetails::getUsername);
    }

}
```